# Possible celery task deadlock?

Tags: python, celery, deadlock

I have this situation:

**tasks.py**

```
@task
def add(a,b):
    return a+b

@task
def other(): 
    chunks = [1,1,1,1] # dummy data

    for index in range(3):
        # wait for each group to finish then continue to the next one
        res = group( add.s(i,i) for i in chunks ).apply_async()
        # sleep for 1 second if group is not ready
        while not res.get():
            time.sleep(1)
```

Could this lead to a deadlock while waiting for the group of tasks to finish ? Even in the theoretical situation of having only 1 celery worker ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are waiting for the result of `group` task inside `other` task. So it might lead to a dead lock even with one celery worker.

Having a task wait for the result of another task is really inefficient, and may even cause a deadlock if the worker pool is exhausted.

**Note:** This just gives a warning in Celery 3.1. But from Celery 3.2 onwards it will raise an exception.

So, it is better to make your design asynchronous. You can do it with a simple modification.

```
@task
def other():

    chunks = [1, 1, 1, 1]
    my_tasks = []

    for i in range(3):
        # delay is shorthand for apply_async. 
        # using si to make signature immutable,so that its arguments don't change
        group_task = group(add.si(i, i) for i in chunks).delay() 
        # here instead of executing them immediately, lets chain them
        my_tasks.append(group_task)

    from celery import chain
    chain(my_tasks)
```

Comment: What if my next execution is depend on output of chain() result. How should I wait for chain() results??